# Match Istio Virtual Services routes for different paths on same port

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm wondering how I can match gRPC routes on the same port. Here's an example of what I was hoping to accomplish with my VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
      prefix: "/custom.api/stream"
    - port: 31400
    route:
    - destination:
        host: stream-handler.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8444
    timeout: 60s
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
  - match:
    - port: 31400
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8443
    timeout: 60s
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
```

So basically: for all requests into 31400 the first match looks for requests to stream at "/custom.api/stream" which has a destination of my stream server.

The second rule as a catch all to gain entry to my main API.

My goal is to have all connections coming through 31400 and then splinter off the request to a dedicated internal service. In the future I'll likely split off services even further (not just for streaming). ie. entire groups of the endpoint might be handled by separate clusters.

When I deploy this rule though the whole VS seems to fail and nothing responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ports are externally exposed in the `Ingressgateway` and should be internally configured using a `Gateway`. The `VirtualService` is intended for layer 7 routing only (once attached to a `Gateway`).

In your *`match`* configuration, you're specifying that the *addressed* host should receive requests in the port 31400, not that the service is listening there. From [the documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest):

> **port**: Specifies the ports on the host that is being addressed. Many services only expose a single port or label ports with the protocols they support, in these cases it is not required to explicitly select the port.

In your case, you might want to create a new `Gateway` to take care of the exposed port's configuration and then, attach the routing part using your `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: grpc-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 31400
      name: grpc
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grpc-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - grcp-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
      exact: "/custom.api/stream"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: stream-handler.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8444
    timeout: 60s
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
  - match:
    - uri:
      prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8443
    timeout: 60s
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
```

Since `match` [cannot be empty](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest), you need to *prefix it* to pick up whatever is coming except for the previous URI *exact* match.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my observations:

1. VirtualService -> `http.match.port`. I don't think `port` is used correctly here. If this is supposed to indicate the listening to incoming requests to port 31400, then this should actually be in the Gateway YAML specification `istio-gateway`.
2. Please share the specification of your Gateway named `istio-gateway`. Basically, it is there where you specify that you are listening to `port.number: 31400`. The VirtualService is where you indicate to which service/host and port you want to route or "splinter off the request".

Please check and see if it helps.