# How to route multiple gRPC services based on path in Istio(Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio

I have managed to run one grpc service in a root path. But I tried to add more grpc service by adding custom path route in virtual service which doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

I have this virtual service routing to only one grpc service and **is working fine**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtual-svc
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - my-gateway
  http:
  - name: "my-grpc-1"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: my-grpc-1-svc
```

But I wanted to try something like below but **it is not working**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtual-svc
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - my-gateway
  http:
  - name: "my-grpc-1"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/my-grpc-1"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: my-grpc-1-svc
  - name: "my-grpc-2"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/my-grpc-2"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: my-grpc-2-svc
```

Comment: Have you tried changeing protocol field in Gateway object to `grpc`?

Comment: Hello @Prata, have you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: @DawidKruk I couldn't use this path prefix match for separate grpc services but what i did was I open different ports in ingress controller for different grpc services

Comment: @Prata glad that you found a workaround. Please consider creating the answer yourself to give more visibility and show the community possible workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some tips when working with grpc and istio (tested with istio 1.9.2).

1.Set protocol in service:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-grpc-service
spec:
  ports:
  - number: 9009
    appProtocol: grpc
```

2.set protocol in gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: grpc
        protocol: GRPC
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

3.grpc generated uri path prefix will be the same as `package` value in .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";    
package somepath;
```

use it as `match.uri.prefix`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtual-svc
spec:
  http:
  - name: "my-grpc-1"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/somepath"
```

Answer (score 0):

That´s probably does not work because your app listen on `/` and with your first virtual service, which works, istio send requests to `/`, which is not happening with your second virtual service.

The answer here would be to add [rewrite](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite) to your second virtual service.

> HTTPRewrite can be used to rewrite specific parts of a HTTP request before forwarding the request to the destination. Rewrite primitive can be used only with HTTPRouteDestination. The following example demonstrates how to rewrite the URL prefix for api call (/ratings) to ratings service before making the actual API call.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ratings-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /ratings
    rewrite:
      uri: /v1/bookRatings
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```

so it would look like this

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtual-svc
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - my-gateway
  http:
  - name: "my-grpc-1"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/my-grpc-1"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: my-grpc-1-svc
  - name: "my-grpc-2"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/my-grpc-2"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: my-grpc-2-svc
```

Related documentation about it is [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/).

---

I think you could try to do it with FQN of the gRPC services as mentioned in this github [issue comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7909#issuecomment-611666678)

Another idea would be to use nginx like mentioned [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14900#issuecomment-418256898).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but It didn't work even though I set this: 'rewrite.uri: /'.  Your solution is not working for grpc but works for http REST services. One solution could be to use domains to route grpc connections/request but I want to use paths for routing.

Comment: What is the issue after you apply your vs for 2 grpc services, you get 404 on both? If you change first prefix from `my-grpc-1` to `/` then first work and second gets 404? Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678561/11977760) could help?

Comment: It is gRPC server there is no 404, 404 is a status code for http server and I don’t have http server in the cluster only gRPC. Problem is gRPC client can’t connect to the gRPC server with path as mentioned in VirtualService... only works with root path.

Answer (score 0):

Convenient way for routing grpc is **Ingress**. But it needs to add some settings for ngnix:

> If you prefer to forward encrypted traffic to your POD and terminate
> TLS at the gRPC server itself, add the ingress annotation 
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPCS".

or else

> Note that gRPC services must be specified as backend services.
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"

[NGINX Ingress Controller: This example demonstrates how to route traffic to a gRPC service through the nginx controller.](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc/)